# Search inside a JXTree

Tags: java, search, swingx

I am trying to perform a search with a JXTree and the searchable interface from swingx but I am not able to find any example and I dont know how it works since I have not used it previously with any other swingx components.

What I do is:

```
tree.getSearchable().search("text to search")
```

but nothing happens within the tree and I am expecting it to filter its content to show the nodes matching the search.

Any examples? Any hints?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the API the method does not filter the tree it just:

> "Returns: index of matched String or
>   -1 if a match cannot be found."

Comment: You're right but then... how is the filtering done? It's one of the swingx characteristics so it should be possible without a lot of effort

Comment: The more recent APIs and the SwingX site seem to be down at the moment.  But I imagine the filtering uses a FilterPipeline, in a very similar pattern to how the HighlighterPipeline works.